# IWebHostBuilder.Configure() not executing in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, app-startup

Why is that a call to `IWebHostBuilder.Configure()` extension method seemingly doesn't do anything in ASP.NET Core (experienced in version 3.4.0)?

For example in this scenario:

```csharp
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
            webBuilder
                .UseSerilog( ... )

                .Configure(appBuilder => // Doesn't do anything.
                    appBuilder.UseSerilogRequestLogging( ... ))

                .UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Here, `UseSerilogRequestLogging()` is called inside `Configure()` to add Serilog's request logging middleware before Startup executes, in order to place it at the beginning of the request pipeline, and also to keep logging-related configuration at one place.

**But** `Configure()` literally doesn't do anything, and the middleware is not added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the `IWebHostBuilder.Configure()` method is not just a general configuration method. It actually registers the provided delegate as `IStartup` in the `ServiceCollection`. See source (albeit old) [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L23).

This means that when `UseStartup<Startup>()` is called subsequently, it **replaces the previously registered delegate**, and thus the configuration in `Configure()` is not executed.

This behavior can be further confirmed if you place `Configure()` after `UseStartup<>()`. In this case, `Configure()` will be the one that replaces `UseStartup<>()`, and `UseStartup()` won't execute.

The documentation on `Configure()` method actually hints at this:

> ```
> //
> // Summary:
> //     Specify the startup method to be used to configure the web application.
> //
> ```

(Answered my own question, to spare some time for someone else who might end up being as perplexed as I was.)